# Manipulate information in CSV file using batch script

Tags: csv, batch-file

I'm trying to manipulate my incoming `CSV` file with a `batch script`.

There are two operations I try to do.

First I convert data from tab separated to `;` separated as well as I add a prefix to every row (FV1). Then I need to manipulate field (9 after adding FV1;) and remove unwanted information `Data should be Information` to `Information` and also row with `zipcode` and `City` in same column (should be splitted into `zipcode;City`)

```
10007   E   L   TKP 1997-03-04      1200    Data should be Information 101  0           K0324-6     106494689   3           5493                                204100922       Address 1  1208         30791   Sirname Lastname        Address 1 1208  12345 City  SE  070-3187878
```

I have this code where I'm able to create the `;` separated file and add the `V1; first`. But the two last parts, I'm unable to solve.

```
                        1           

@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "inputfile=C:\Temp\test_in.txt"
set "outputfile=C:\Temp\test_out.txt"

::There should be a TAB character after the equal below
set "tab=   "
set "space= "

  for /f "delims= skip=1" %%A in ('findstr /rn "^" %inputfile%') do (
    set ln=%%A
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    set "ln=!ln:*:=!"
    if defined ln set "ln=!ln:%tab%=;!"
    set "outputdata=V1;!ln!"
::    echo !outputdata!
    for /F "delims=; tokens=35" %%a in (%outputdata%) do (
    set string=%%a & echo !string:%space%=;!
    echo !string!)
    endlocal
) >> %outputfile%
```

Comment: You should indicate in your data sample where the Tabs actually are.

Comment: You should also provide a sample (suiting the input sample) that shows the converted output...

Comment: So you are saying that **12345 City** is in one tab delimited field but the STATE is in its own field?